# matplotlib tight_layout + gridspec + fig.suptitle looks bad

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a very nice GridSpec graph using Matplotlib 2.2.2 but I can't make a pretty title for the figure as a whole. Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline

def example(tl):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14,8))
    hr = [3,3,3,1,1]
    wr = [3,1]
    ny = len(hr)
    nx = len(wr)
    gs = gridspec.GridSpec(ny,nx,
                        height_ratios=hr,
                        width_ratios=wr,
                        hspace=0.08, wspace=0.1)
    for j in xrange(nx):
        ax = [fig.add_subplot(gs[0,j])]
        ax += [fig.add_subplot(gs[i,j], sharex=ax[0]) for i in xrange(1,ny)]
        for axi in ax:
              axi.plot([0,1,2],[0,1,4])    
    fig.suptitle('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.')
    if tl:
        gs.tight_layout(fig)
```

If I run `example(False)` for no tight layout I get a huge amount of space above the figures:

[image]

If I run `example(True)` for a tight layout I get negative space:

[image]

How can I fix this and get a figure-level title with a proper amount of margin from the subplots?

Comment: you can set `x` and `y` location for the `suptitle` with additional argument  e.g. color font fontsize etc. https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.suptitle.html. probably `y=0.91` is a better location than the default value of 0.98

Comment: @KhalilAlHooti could you post as an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`tight_layout()` does not take figure level artists into account.

### Use constrained_layout

However, there is a relatively new alternative, called [`constrained_layout`](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/constrainedlayout_guide.html). Using this, the figure title will be included. Note that for this to work you need to supply the figure to the `GridSpec` via it's `figure` argument.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

def example(tl):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14,8), constrained_layout=tl)
    hr = [3,3,3,1,1]
    wr = [3,1]
    ny = len(hr)
    nx = len(wr)
    gs = gridspec.GridSpec(ny,nx, figure=fig,
                        height_ratios=hr,
                        width_ratios=wr,
                        hspace=0.08, wspace=0.1)
    for j in range(nx):
        ax = [fig.add_subplot(gs[0,j])]
        ax += [fig.add_subplot(gs[i,j], sharex=ax[0]) for i in range(1,ny)]
        for axi in ax:
              axi.plot([0,1,2],[0,1,4])    
    fig.suptitle('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.')


example(True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

### Update top margin

Alternatively you can update the top margin *after* calling `tight_layout`. E.g. as

```
gs.update(top=0.95)
```

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

def example(tl):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14,8))
    hr = [3,3,3,1,1]
    wr = [3,1]
    ny = len(hr)
    nx = len(wr)
    gs = gridspec.GridSpec(ny,nx, figure=fig,
                        height_ratios=hr,
                        width_ratios=wr,
                        hspace=0.08, wspace=0.1)
    for j in range(nx):
        ax = [fig.add_subplot(gs[0,j])]
        ax += [fig.add_subplot(gs[i,j], sharex=ax[0]) for i in range(1,ny)]
        for axi in ax:
              axi.plot([0,1,2],[0,1,4])    
    fig.suptitle('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.')
    if tl:
        gs.tight_layout(fig)
        gs.update(top=0.95)


example(True)
plt.show()
```

[image]